# iTerm2+tmux+emacs: differentiating between <tab> and <Ctrl-i>

Tags: emacs, tmux, iterm2

Mac OS 10.7.5

Org-mode plus Evil minor mode. In org-mode `<Tab>` cycles through outline levels shown. While Evil binds `<Ctrl-i>` to forward jump traversing the jump list.

All is well is Gui Emacs.

However using Emacs in iTerm within a tmux session (preferred option), `<Tab>` and `<Ctrl-i>` are the same. Thus, both `<Tab>` key and `<Ctrl-i>` execute Evil's forward jump.

I know that iTerm can send escape sequences: what is the right way (if any) to setup the Tab key in iTerm2 to differentiate between `<Tab>` and `<Ctrl-i>`?

Comment: The terminal is the limiting factor here.  It sends Emacs the same thing when you type `TAB` or `C-i`, so Emacs can't distinguish them.  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Named-ASCII-Chars.html.  Use the GUI or pick different keybindings.